# Смена значений указателей при помощи функции

Tags: c, функции, указатели

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void){
    int *PointerOne,*PointerTwo,*PointerThree;
    int a=5,b=8;
    PointerOne=&a;
    PointerTwo=&b;
    PointerThree=PointerOne;
    PointerOne=PointerTwo;
    PointerTwo=PointerThree;
    printf("%d,%d",*PointerTwo,*PointerOne);
}                          //*Это меняет значения указателей без проблем*//


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void change_positions(int PointerOne,int PointerTwo){
    int *PointerThree;
    PointerThree=PointerOne;
    PointerOne=PointerTwo;
    PointerTwo=PointerThree;
}

void main(void){
    int *PointerOne,*PointerTwo;
    int a=5,b=8;
    PointerOne=&a;
    PointerTwo=&b;
    printf("%d,%d",*PointerTwo,*PointerOne);
}             //*Это не меняет значения указателей при использовании функции*//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void swap(int * p, int * q)
{
    int tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}


void main(void){
    int *pone,*ptwo;
    int a=5,b=8;
    pone=&a;
    ptwo=&b;
    printf("%d    %d\n",pone,ptwo);
    swap(pone,ptwo);
    printf("%d    %d",pone,ptwo);
}             //*Это меняет *pone-*ptwo ,то-есть a и b,но не меняют адреса указателей pone - ptwo //
```

Дело вот в чём,когда я пытаюсь изменить 2 указателя самостоятельно,без функции то всё работает ,но когда вызываю функцию для этого - Одна которая (,,работает'') -в которой изменяются адреса указателей,, и другая - с функцией в которой (,,не работает'') не изменяются адреса указателей. Мне нужно что-бы именно менялись адреса указателей,как в первом коде.Т.е.
 До смены 23425678 23425679
 После    23425679 23425678  //адреса меняются 
Что изменить в функции что-бы указатели менялись между ними?

Comment: Приведите нормальный код в текстовом виде - ведь то, что вы приводите, даже отформатировать нормально нельзя! Опять же - что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Кстати, у вас вообще функция описана, как принимающая `int`, передаете вы в нее - по значению - *копии* указателей, меняете эти копии, а не реальные значения переменных...

Comment: Ваш код, который "Не работает :(", даже компилироваться не будет. Как уже сказали, функция должна тип `int*` принимать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, вот так будет корректно работать:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int * p, int * q)
{
    int tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 3;
    int * pa = &a, * pb = &b;
    printf("%d  --  %d\n",a,b);
    swap(pa,pb);
    printf("%d  --  %d\n",a,b);
}
```

(см. http://ideone.com/lkEusl) Посмотрите, что передается в функцию, и что меняется в ней.

В нее передаются *указатели*, и меняются *значения, расположенные в соответствующих местах памяти*, на которые они указывают.

**Update**
Ну, если вам хочется менять указатели - то используйте указатели на них:

```
void swap(int ** p, int ** q)
{
    int *tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}
```

вызов соответственно:

```
swap(&pa,&pb);
```

Comment: Ваша функция ,как я проверил,изменяет лишь значение a-b,*pa-*pb,но адреса функции не меняются. Мне нужно что-бы менялись именно адреса указателей.
http://ideone.com/39iSPO

Comment: См. Обновление в ответе

Comment: Не знал что так можно,буду иметь в виду.

Comment: Указатель - он тоже просто переменная, на которую можно указать :)